# Can't app.use two different routers in my index.js file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, router

Hi there I am trying to create a react app and I am having trouble with the backend.

I have an index file like this

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const db = require('./db')
const bookRouter = require('./routes/book-router')
const userRouter = require('./routes/user-router')



const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8174

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json())

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello People!')
})


//set up routes
app.use('/api', bookRouter) // the issue is here
app.use('/user', userRouter)
//commenting one of these lines makes the app work

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

so the reason my app is not working is at fault of the app.use if I comment one of them out the server runs fine, but if I leave them both in the file not commented out then they app will crash with this error

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8174
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1280:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1415:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/devinshawntripp/unt-library-system/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/devinshawntripp/unt-library-system/server/index.js:30:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1307:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: userRouter is not imported, and why do you want 2 different routers for the same base URL `/api`

Comment: it is but its not in the code ill update it

Comment: Make sure you don't have two `listen` calls anywhere in your code.

Comment: @AKX thank you I double checked I didn't see any

Comment: Then also make sure you're not accidentally running the app twice. The error is related to that, not multiple routers...

Answer (score 0):

userRouter is not imported.

You could try something like below,

```
app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    userRouter(req, res, next);
    bookRouter(req, res, next);
})
```

Error is not caused because of 2 routers, it's because of the port is already in use.

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8174`

Comment: i didn't actually want to use /api for both of them sorry i edited the question

Comment: Well, like I said if I comment out one of the app.use like for example the app.use('/api', bookRouter) or if I comment out the one with userRouter then the server runs perfectly: [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server running on port 8174
Connect to mongodb established

Comment: actually I take that back it will work if i use '/api' for both of them but if I change one to ./user or something it breaks

Comment: ok so I did a ps aux and found all the instances of node running and killed them all and then ran nodemon again and now it works lol